# Promise is undefined in webpack bundle file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, es6-promise

I have a React/Redux app that uses webpack and babel-polyfill. However, in IE11, I am getting the following error: `SCRIPT5009: 'Promise' is undefined.`

**Before this gets marked as a duplicate question:** 
*I know this is typically associated using ES6 syntax in browsers that don't fully support it, without using some type of polyfill.*

My problem is that I am currently using webpack and babel-polyfill, in the same format as other projects we have which work in IE11, but I still get this error.

The error points to a line in my webpack-generated bundle file, the line of code seems to be coming from my superagent node_module (line: 92993 in myDashboardBundle.js):

```
this._fullfilledPromise = new Promise(function(innerResolve, innerReject) {
  self.end(function(err, res) {
    if (err) innerReject(err);
    else innerResolve(res);
  });
});
```

My project has webpack 3.5.5 and babel 6.26.0 and es6-promise 2.3.0 installed in yarn / npm (we switched over from npm to yarn last year).

In my webpack.common.js, I'm including babel-polyfill in my entry and babel-loader in my loader:

```
'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
  entry: [
    "./myDashboard.js",
    'babel-polyfill',
  ],
  output: {
    filename: "myDashboardBundle.js",

  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve('./'),
      'node_modules',
    ]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        include: __dirname,
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loaders: ['style-loader', 'raw-loader'],
        include: __dirname
      }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
  ],
};
```

In my .babelrc, I am targeting Explorer 11 in the browser presets:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 52,
        "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "safari 7", "Explorer 11"]
      }
    }],
    ["es2015", {"modules": false}],
    "stage-0",
    "react",
   ],
  "plugins": [
    "emotion",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}
```

I have seen suggestions to place 'babel-polyfill' above './myDashboard.js', but the error still persists. I have also seen suggestions to import es6-promise and call .polyfill(), however this errors out as well as the module comes up undefined.

If anyone has encountered an error similar to this, or has any insight as to how I could resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you include the code where you are importing `babel-polyfill` and `es6-promise`?

Comment: at the top of my webpack.common.js
`

'use strict';
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require("webpack");

`
they've all been downloaded through yarn/npm. I thought babel / es6-promise would be included with the require("webpack") call, as our other projects don't call for babel and es6-promise in specific require statements

Comment: Ah, I see. The webpack file will not be a part of the final bundle that is sent to the browser. Have you tried importing them at the top of your `myDashboard.js` file instead?

Comment: Hmm, I tried:
`import Promise from 'es6-promise';`
however, that brought up this error:
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'es6-promise'`, which is confusing, as I can see babel-polyfill@^6.26.0 in my yarn.lock

Comment: `babel-polyfill` and `es6-promise` are separate packages. If you write `npm i -S es6-promise` and then `import 'es6-promise/auto'` at the top of `Dashboard.js` it might work.

Comment: although I really appreciate the effort, that solution did not work. 

I installed es6-promise with `npm i -S es6-promise`, and imported it in myDashboard.js with `import 'es6-promise/auto';` However, I still get the error regarding myDashboardBundle.js trying to call Promise via superagent, and Promise being undefined when that happens.

Comment: try placing `"babel-polyfill"` before `"./myDashboard.js"` in the entry array, what happens?

Comment: @axm__, unfortunately, I get the same result of Promise not being defined in the webpack-generated myDashboardBundle.js file

Comment: You could try to refer to [this article](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-polyfill) and using the following code to import promise: "var Promise = require('promise-polyfill').default;"